# Simple line drawing animation in Swift

Tags: swift, swift2, core-animation, drawrect, uibezierpath

I am new to swift and got frustrated with this issue that I'm having.

What I am trying to do is very simple: draw a straight line in the center of the screen and animate it. Sounds very simple, right? Yeah.. so that's what I have at the moment.

```html
import UIKit

class Drawings: UIView {


    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        let screensize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        let screenWidth = screensize.width
        let screenHeight = screensize.height

        //context
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 7.0)
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor)

        //path
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, screenWidth, screenHeight * 0.5)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, screenWidth * 0.5, screenHeight * 0.5)

        CGContextSetLineCap(context, CGLineCap.Round)

        //draw
        CGContextStrokePath(context)

    }

}
```

The reason I'm asking is that I've found that I cannot animate it, since it's in drawRect function. Is that true? Need some explanation from you guys. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't access the screen or it's size. Use `self.bounds` to figure out where to draw (and don't draw outside those bounds). The `drawRect:` is used "once" (you can cause it to be redrawn) to perform drawing for a view, and the local coordinate system is in effect.

Comment: In case you haven't seen Apple's [iOS Drawing Concepts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html)

Comment: Note (unimportant at this point): the `rect` parameter is usually equivalent to the bounds. It may be a subset, which says "you only *need* to draw part of the frame. It's common to redraw it all (unless you have a complex, costly view).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't draw shapes in `drawRect` like this, especially if you're going to animate.

Instead, make a CAShapeLayer, and you can use Core Animation to animate that.

```
// Create the path using UIBezierPath.
// Position can start at 0,0 because we'll move it using the layer
let linePath = UIBezierPath()
linePath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
linePath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(frame), y: 0))

// Create the shape layer that will draw the path
let lineLayer = CAShapeLayer()

// set the bounds to the size of the path. 
// You could also set to the size of your view, 
// but if i know the size of my shape ahead of time, 
// I like to set it to be the same.
lineLayer.bounds = linePath.bounds

// give it the same position as our view's layer.
// layers have an anchor point of 0.5, 0.5 (their center)
// so this will put the layer in the center of the view.
lineLayer.position = layer.position

// finally, set up the shape properties. set the path and stroke etc
lineLayer.path = linePath.CGPath
lineLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
lineLayer.lineWidth = 4

// add it to your view's layer and you're done!
layer.addSublayer(lineLayer)
```

Now you can animate properties on `lineLayer` using Core Animation.

Comment: Thank you! Really helped me a lot